Pauli errors and correction before non-Clifford gate
If we have a circuit of Clifford gates, any Pauli gates (such as those required by error correction) can be pushed to the end of the circuit. However, when we have a non-Clifford gate like a T-gate, we must do the Pauli corrections immediately since these non-Clifford gates can turn Pauli corrections into non-Pauli corrections.
When we implement a T-gate via magic states, we see this in action. Consider this circuit (source: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-023-42482-1)

The S-gate is non-Pauli and therefore we must wait to know the outcome of the Z measurement reliably, implement the S-gate, and then continue with the rest of the circuit.
Now consider this implementation of the T-gate from this paper - https://arxiv.org/pdf/2405.03970.

The idea here is that the output register has a Pauli correction that depends on the bits $s$ and $m$. Why can't one continue with the rest of the circuit and push this $Z^{s\oplus m}$ gate (if it turns out to be needed) to the end of the circuit, even if there are more T-gates? We would simply collect all the $s$ and $m$ outcomes from each T-gate slowly and the only correction is a Z gate which seems like it can be pushed to the end of the circuit. What is the error in this argument?

If there are Hadamard gates later in the circuit, then the $Z^{s\oplus m}$ gets converted into $X^{s\oplus m}$, so it doesn't commute with later $T$ gates. You need to implement that correction before the next $T$ gate.

Sorry, even if it is X, it is still a Pauli so why can't it be pushed to the end? The next T-gate also consists of CNOTs, Z and S gates (depending on the outcomes $m$ and $s$ in its circuit) and also measurements. So why can't we delay the implementation of the X from the first T-gate to the end of the subsequent T-gate?
